# Can't get response code

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I want to get user AccessToken.

When the user clicks on Register/Login button :

```
            $.ajax({
            url: 'Register',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { m:true },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                } else {
                }
            },
            error: function () {
            }
            });
```

My register method :

```
            Uri uri = new Uri(FacebookHelpers.GetFacebookLoginURL());
            var res = await FacebookHelpers.FacebookRequest<object>(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

In res, i want to get result from FacebookRequest to get code, than exchange that code for access token.

My GetFacebookLoginUrl function :

```
            var redirectUri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
            var uri = GetUri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth",
                Tuple.Create("client_id", FacebookAppId),
                Tuple.Create("redirect_uri", redirectUri),
                Tuple.Create("response_type", "code"),
                Tuple.Create("scope", "public_profile,email"),
                Tuple.Create("state", Convert.ToString(new Random().Next(9999)))
                );
```

In my FacebookRequest function :

```
        public static async Task<T> FacebookRequest<T>(Uri uri)
        {
            string json;
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                json = await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            try
            {
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
                return result;
            }
            catch (JsonException ex)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Unable to deserialize the Facebook response.", ex);
            }
        }
```

The issue appears when FacebookRequest function tries to get code from provided URL.

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line
>   0, position 0.

Json response contains same page from where method has been called.
FacebookRequest does not returns code, it returns success instead.

Any idea ?

The goal : I want to get user from my database and link its account with my bot. Or if user does not exist, first register and than link with the bot.

Comment: Have you checked what your `json` variable actually contains …?

Comment: I edited my question. It contains whole html from where method is called...

Comment: You can not load the Facebook login dialog in the background - you have to redirect the user to that address. (For the absolutely obvious reason that users need to be able to verify via the address bar that they are indeed entering their credentials to Facebook, and not a phishing site.)

Comment: Its not about phishing :  I want to get user from my database and link its account with my bot. Or if user does not exist, first register and than link with the bot.

Comment: Doesn’t change the fact that you need to send the user to `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/...` either via a link or an automatic redirect. It has to be called _in the user’s browser_; if you try and request it in the background, that won’t work.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Should i get first code and than exchange it for access token, or can i get access token directly ?

Comment: You can specify that you want an access token returned directly - but in that case, the token is passed in the fragment part of your redirect URI, meaning you can only get it from there using client-side code. That is rather not an option here, I suppose.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Please add your last comment as an answer to mark ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not load the Facebook login dialog in the background - you have to redirect the user to that address. It has to be called in the user’s browser; if you try and request it in the background, that won’t work.

As for whether you get a code or an access token returned: You can specify that you want an access token returned directly - but in that case, the token is passed in the fragment part of your redirect URI, meaning you can only get it from there using client-side code. That is rather not an option here, I suppose. (If you need more info on that, the parameter `response_type` and possible values are described here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#logindialog)

Comment: Thank you one more time :)))